# access google analytics api withouth authentication

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk, google-analytics-filters

I have managed to obtain info from an "view" using php in the google analytics, however it only works if i authenticate with the google account, otherwise it displays the following error:

"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling POST https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet: (403) User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.'"

what i need basically is to find a way of obtaining the "view info" without authenticating, since i have a custom cms and i need to show this info in the cms admin section

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('pathToFile.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  // Set the access token on the client.
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

  // Create an authorized analytics service object.
  $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

  // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
  $response = getReport($analytics);

  // Print the response.
  $info = printResults($response);

} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/api/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


function getReport(&$analytics) {

  // Replace with your view ID. E.g., XXXX.
  $VIEW_ID = "VIEW_ID_NUMBER";

  // Create the DateRange object.
  $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
  $dateRange->setStartDate("2016-01-01");
  $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

  // Create the Metrics object.
  $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
  $sessions->setExpression("ga:goalCompletionsAll");
  $sessions->setAlias("objetivos");

  //Create the Dimensions object.
  $medium = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
  $medium->setName("ga:medium");

  $minute = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
  $minute->setName("ga:minute");

  $hour = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
  $hour->setName("ga:hour");

  $date = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
  $date->setName("ga:date");

  $day = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Dimension();
  $day->setName("ga:day");

  $goals = new Google_Service_Analyticsreporting_Metric();
  $goals->setExpression("ga:goalStartsAll");

  // Create the ReportRequest object.
  $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
  $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
  $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
  $request->setDimensions(array($medium, $date, $hour, $minute));
  $request->setMetrics(array($sessions, $goals));

  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
  return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


?>
```

any info regarding this subject is greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: So you want to access login-protected data without loggin in? Do you really expect any help here? If you wan't to show the data in the cms, you need to login (or whoever owns the account). There is a javascript API for google analytics: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/ Maybe this will help.

Comment: @Seb sorry i didn't explain myself correctly. What i need is to obtain the info without having to sign in with the google account, if its possible to send the credentials through php or something like that.

Comment: @SolarConfinement Please read Google OAuth 2.0 Documentation for the same. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

Comment: @SolarConfinement Then please edit your question because it cleary says there: "what i need basically is to find a way of obtaining the "view info" without authenticating" - and this is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **service account** to access Google Analytics data without the Google authentication screen.

**Create a service account and key**

In the Google API Console (https://console.developers.google.com/), navigate to the *Credentials* tab. Under *Create credentials*, select *Service account key*. Choose a nice name and under *Role* I selected *Project-->Viewer*, which I can confirm to work. Under *Key type*, select *JSON* and click the *Create* button. A JSON file is downloaded to your system which **you should look after** since it's the only copy. You can't download it again later, so losing it will render that service account useless.

**Give the account access to the Google Analytics view's data**

The JSON file contains the Google Account (an e-mail address ending with *iam.gserviceaccount.com*). Copy that e-mail address and give it *Read and analyze* permissions on the Google Analytics *view* you want to have access to.

Answer (score 1):

To get any information about GA you need to authenticate yourselfself.
If you do not want to use authentification path with the pop up windows you can use the "p12 key" to workaround this issue. The p12 files need to be attached to you request and there is no need to be logged (this is the solution for server side application), but this only work with your own data, so the ownder of the p12 key need to have access The desired account

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization

Check this to know how to get the p12 
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/how-where-to-obtain-a-p12-key-file-from-the-google-developers-console